# How do I possibly fix a web application that does not display certain templates but not throw a 'Template not found error'?

Tags: html, templates, flask, backend

I've defined the routes for rendering the templates in my views.py file and when I click on the links the browser navigates to the specific pages but nothing is displayed and no error is thrown.

I tried inspecting the console and I found this issue:

A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.

I unfortunately couldn't diagnose the issue since I'm pretty much a beginner.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> You can create a html page for error handling.For example , if template not found error , then you will show the error page

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
   return render_template('404.html'),404
```

> Please add the above in init file .After then create a file named '404.html'
> In this file your write your own content for showing error message. This will help to template not fount error.

Comment: I don't think you read my question thoroughly because I've clearly specified that it doesn't throw a 'Template not found error' but the issue rather is potentially with the console which I included the details in my question.